# image slider using eq() to get the images trying change it to a var of images

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use this image slider to get the images from a folder location and not use .eq() to get the images but I can't flipping figure out how to do it.

```
var pages = $('#container li'),
    current = 0;
var currentPage, nextPage;
var get_images = new Array("1.jpg", "2.jpg");
var handler = function () {
    $('#container .button').unbind('click');
    currentPage = pages.eq(current);
    if ($(this).hasClass('prevButton')) {
        if (current <= 0) current = pages.length - 1;
        else current = current - 1;
        nextPage = pages.eq(current);

        nextPage.css("marginLeft", -604);
        nextPage.show();
        nextPage.animate({
            marginLeft: 0
        }, 800, function () {
            currentPage.hide();
        });
        currentPage.animate({
            marginLeft: 604
        }, 800, function () {
            $('#container .button').bind('click', handler);
        });
    } else {

        if (current >= pages.length - 1) current = 0;
        else current = current + 1;
        nextPage = pages.eq(current);

        nextPage.css("marginLeft", 604);
        nextPage.show();
        nextPage.animate({
            marginLeft: 0
        }, 800, function () {});
        currentPage.animate({
            marginLeft: -604
        }, 800, function () {
            currentPage.hide();
            $('#container .button').bind('click', handler);
        });
    }
}

$('#container .button').click(handler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be more difficult than just replacing instances of the `.eq()`, because it's working with DOM elements that we can use `.css()` and `.animate()` against, as they're already in the DOM.

I think it would be best just to do

```
$.each(get_images, function(i,img){
    $('#container').append('<li><img src="'+img+'"/></li>');
});
```

Then call all the other code after.

**edit**

[Here's a jsFiddle with my adaptation of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/dWCwZ/)

I simply used bootstrap and a random thumbnail generator, don't pay attention to it in the code. Focus on the `get_images` variable, and the `$.each()` function